# Using a JAR package that uses a different Java version in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Java 8 and I've been trying to use a JAR package that uses JRE 6.
In 'Create a Java Project' I used the 'Use a project specific JRE' and also
created a run configuration but when I try to set the alternate JRE to 6, the 'run' button gets blocked out. Are they not compatible or am I missing a step? I've also tried changing the PATH destination, though I'm not sure if that is even relevant to my problem.

EDIT: I am using a JAR package from an online source that is Java 6 compatible and am trying to integrate it into Eclipse Mars with Java 8 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few items to check, under **Project settings:** (most of these can be set workspace-wide as well)

- Java Build Path > Libraries. Replace JRE System Library with a jdk6 execution environment or alternate JRE
- Java Compiler > JDK compliance. Set to 1.6

**System:**

Check Installed JREs and Execution environments. Make sure a JRE is linked to the Execution Environment for JavaSE-1.6 (with the checkbox).

Comment: That fixed the issue but now I have a different issue. However, it is unrelated. I'll just figure it out myself. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad that helped. Thanks for accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just adding the external JAR to the project? Most (non-executable) JARs that were originally made for older versions of java should still work today.

To add an external JAR: right-click on your project in the package explorer and go to `Build Path >> Add External Archives...` then select your JAR from there. Be sure to leave the project set up for JRE8.

The reason that your `run` button is blocked out when you switched to JRE6 was because Eclipse detected that it was not installed and therefore cannot run it as JRE6.